# java: how many times is the collection expression evaluated in a "foreach"

Tags: java, performance, collections, foreach

if I do this in Java:

```
for(String s : myCollection.expensiveListGeneration())
{
      doSomething();
}
```

is expensiveListGeneration() invoked just once at the beggining or in every cycle iteration?

Is it implementation dependent?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java foreach efficiency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/904582/java-foreach-efficiency)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

because it is equivalent to using an iterator, it is equivalent to calling the collections' . iterator() method, and it is called once.

Answer (score 32):

It's invoked once, and not implementation dependant. The for-each loop is based on the [`Iterable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface. All it does is call the collection's `iterator()` method once at the beginning, and then works with that iterator.