# In a java enhanced for loop, is it safe to assume the expression to be looped over will be evaluated only once?

Tags: java, arrays, foreach, iteration

In Java, a for-each loop.
If I have a method that generates an array, called `genArray()`.

In the following code, will the array each time be re-generated by calling `genArray()`?
Or will Java call once the method and store a copy from the array?

```
for (String s : genArray())
{
    //...
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Of course, the easiest way to know is to test that... A simple System.out.println() in genArray() is enough!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java foreach efficiency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/904582/java-foreach-efficiency)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

About [the enhanced for statement](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.14.2), the Java Language Specifications writes:

> The enhanced for statement has the
>   form:
>
> ```
> EnhancedForStatement:
>         for ( VariableModifiersopt Type Identifier: Expression) Statement
> ```
>
> The Expression must either have type
>   `Iterable` or else it must be of an
>   array type (§10.1), or a compile-time
>   error occurs.
>
> The scope of a local variable declared
>   in the FormalParameter part of an
>   enhanced `for` statement (§14.14) is
>   the contained Statement
>
> The meaning of the enhanced `for`
>   statement is given by translation into
>   a basic `for` statement.
>
> If the type of *`Expression`* is a
>   subtype of `Iterable`, then let *`I`* be
>   the type of the expression
>   *Expression.*`iterator()`. The enhanced `for` statement is equivalent
>   to a basic `for` statement of the
>   form:
>
> ```
> for (I #i = Expression.iterator(); #i.hasNext(); ) {
>
>         VariableModifiersopt Type Identifier = #i.next();
>    Statement
> }
> ```
>
> Where *`#i`* is a compiler-generated
>   identifier that is distinct from any
>   other identifiers (compiler-generated
>   or otherwise) that are in scope (§6.3)
>   at the point where the enhanced for
>   statement occurs.
>
> Otherwise, the Expression necessarily
>   has an array type, *`T[]`*. Let *`L1 ... Lm`*
>   be the (possibly empty) sequence of
>   labels immediately preceding the
>   enhanced `for` statement. Then the
>   meaning of the enhanced for statement
>   is given by the following basic `for`
>   statement:
>
> ```
> T[] a = Expression;
> L1: L2: ... Lm:
> for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
>         VariableModifiersopt Type Identifier = a[i];
>         Statement
> }
> ```
>
> Where *a* and *i* are compiler-generated
>   identifiers that are distinct from any
>   other identifiers (compiler-generated
>   or otherwise) that are in scope at the
>   point where the enhanced for statement
>   occurs.

So in your case, `genArray()` doesn't return a subtype of `Iterable` but an array type, so your enhanced `for` statement is equivalent to the following basic `for` statement:

```
String[] a = genArray();
...
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    String s = a[i];
    // ...
}
```

And `genArray()` will thus be called only once (but the currently accepted answer is partially wrong).

Answer (score 5):

Java will call genArray() once, get the iterator object, and call that multiple times.

Comment: This answer is partially **wrong**. Yes, Java will call `genArray()` only once but, no, `java.lang.Array` isn't a subtype of `Iterable` so Java won't get an iterator object.

Answer (score 5):

It should only get used once - it's the same as calling this:

```
  String[] strings = genArray();
  for (String s : strings) {
  ...
```