# In Java, does calling a field accessor in a loop create a new reference on each iteration of the loop?

Tags: java, optimization, loops

Say I have a loop like

```
for (Foo aType : bar.getAList()) {
   if (aType.getBaz().equals(baz)) {

   return aType;
   }
}
```

`bar.getAList()` is called on each iteration of the loop. Does the JVM/compiler keep track of the fact that this is the same object, or does it naively call the method and create a reference to the List each time?

Additionally, is this anything at all to worry about (recalling Jackson, Knuth, and Wulf's aphorisms regarding optimization)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [java for each loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433282/java-for-each-loop)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

bar.getAList() isn't called in each iteration. The code is simplified into this during compilation :

```
for(Iterator<Foo> it = bar.getAList().iterator(); it.hasNext();){
    Foo aType = it.next();
    //...
}
```

---

**Resources :**

- [oracle.com - The for-each loop](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)

Comment: Excellent, that's exactly the information what I was looking for.