# What mean in for loop condition this line?

Tags: java, for-loop, iteration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java for loop syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763131/java-for-loop-syntax)

```
for (File file : files){
    ...body...
}
```

What mean in for loop condition this line?

Answer (score 2):

This is java [for-each](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/jsr/tiger/enhanced-for.html) (or) enhanced for loop

This means for each file in files array (or) iterable.

Answer (score 0):

`for (File file : files)` -- is foreach loop in Java  same as saying, `for each file in files`. Where `files` is an iterable and `file` is the variable where each element stored temporarily valid withing the for-loop scope. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

Answer (score 0):

This says for-each file in a set fo files do ... (body)

Read about [The For-Each Loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) for more details. The examples in the link where great.

Answer (score 0):

**-** This form of loop came into existence in Java from `1.5`, and is know as `For-Each Loop`.

**Lets see how it works:**

**For Loop:**

```
int[] arr = new int[5];    // Put some values in

for(int i=0 ; i<5 ; i++){  

// Initialization, Condition and Increment needed to be handled by the programmer

// i mean the index here

   System.out.println(arr[i]);

}
```

**For-Each Loop:**

```
int[] arr = new int[5];    // Put some values in

for(int i : arr){  

// Initialization, Condition and Increment needed to be handled by the JVM

// i mean the value at an index in Array arr

// Its assignment of values from Array arr into the variable i which is of same type, in an incremental index order

   System.out.println(i);

}
```