# How would I save items in my class with description and price? Or how would I go about it? with the addItem method?

Tags: java

all of the methods where blank, my hw told to follow the comments and fill them in. Just having trouble putting the array items and description together.

```
public class CashRegisterItemList {
private ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
private double taxRate;

/**
 * Constructs a cash register with with no items. 
 * Sets the tax rate to the default of 7.25%. * 
 */
public CashRegisterItemList() {
    items=0;
    double taxRate= 7.25;

}

/**
 * Constructs a cash register with no items. 
 * Sets the tax rate to the given tax rate.
 * @param taxRate tax rate for taxable items
 */
public CashRegisterItemList(double taxRate) {
    items= 0;
    double taxRate= taxRate;
}

/**
 * Adds an item to this cash register.
 * @param description the description of this item
 * @param price the price of this item
 * @param isTaxable the taxability of this item
 */
public void addItem(String description, double price, boolean isTaxable) {
    itemCount++;
    totalPrice = totalPrice + price;
    if(description isTaxable)
        totalTax = price*taxRate;       

    }

/**
 * Gets the total price of all items in the current sale,
 * not including the tax.
 * @return the total amount
 */
public double getTotal() {
    return totalPrice;
}

/**
 * Gets the total tax of all the taxable items in the current sale,
 * @return the total tax
 */
public double getTotalTax() {
     return totalTax;
    }

/**
 * Gets the number of items in the current sale.
 * @return the item count
 */
public int getCount() {
    return items;
}

/**
 * Removes all items from current sale
 */
public void clear() {
    int items= 0;
}

/**
 * Prints a receipt, in the form shown on the assignment page.
 */
public void printReceipt() {

    for(int i=0; i< items.length; i++){
        if  

}

}
```

Would create a separate variable to solely keep track of items? What do 
i do to make this work.
this class is supposed to create the output of a cash register like

```
Cash Register 1 has 6 items Cash Register 1 total = 30.10
Cash Register 1 Receipt
6 items
Bread 0.90
          Paper     1.95 T
        Bananas     0.90
           Milk     1.95
         Turkey    21.50
Bowl +
    2.90 T
--------
   30.10
0.35T -------- 30.45
Cash Register 1 Receipt
6 items
Bread 0.90
          Paper     1.95 T
        Bananas     0.90
           Milk     1.95
         Turkey    21.50
Bowl +
After clearing
Cash Register 1
0 items
                --------
                    0.00
0.00T -------- 0.00
```

here is the item.java

```
public class Item {
    private String description;
    private double price;
    private boolean isTaxable;

    /**
     * Constructs an Item with a given description, price and taxability.
     * @param description the description of item
     * @param price the price of item
     * @param isTaxable whether the item is taxable or not
     */
    public Item(String description, double price, boolean isTaxable) {
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
        this.isTaxable = isTaxable;
    }
    /**
     * Returns the description of the item.
     * @return the description of the item
     */
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    /**
     * Returns the price of the item.
     * @return the price of the item
     */
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    /**
     * Returns true if item is taxable, false otherwise
     * @return true if item is taxable, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean isTaxable() {
        return isTaxable;
    }

}
```

and the item tester

```
public class CashRegisterItemListTester {

public static void main(String[] args) {
CashRegisterItemList register1 = new CashRegisterItemList();

    register1.addItem("Bread", 0.90, false);
    register1.addItem("Paper", 1.95, true);
    register1.addItem("Bananas", 0.90, false);
    register1.addItem("Milk", 1.95, false);
    register1.addItem("Turkey", 21.50, false);
    register1.addItem("Bowl", 2.90, true);
    System.out.printf("Cash Register 1 has %d items\n", register1.getCount());
    System.out.printf("Cash Register 1 total = %.2f\n", register1.getTotal());
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Cash Register 1 Receipt");
    register1.printReceipt();

    register1 = new CashRegisterItemList(0.085);
    register1.addItem("Bread", 0.90, false);
    register1.addItem("Paper", 1.95, true);
    register1.addItem("Bananas", 0.90, false);
    register1.addItem("Milk", 1.95, false);
    register1.addItem("Turkey", 21.50, false);
    register1.addItem("Bowl", 2.90, true);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Cash Register 1 Receipt");
    register1.printReceipt();

    register1.clear();
    System.out.println("\nAfter clearing");
    System.out.println("Cash Register 1");
    register1.printReceipt();

}

}
```

Comment: I havent completely finished it, so it wont print anything.

Comment: The [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) holds type `Item`. I'm pretty sure that isn't a built-in class (although my Java knowledge is rusty). Did the teacher give you an `Item` class? It seems to me that that class is the key to your problem.

Comment: @acattle yes he gave us a itemtesterlist and the items i will add them right now.

Comment: Reading your code I see you have a few other mistakes (that aren't part of your original question). I suggest you look at the [`ArrayList` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). For starters, the `size()` function might be useful to you. Also, read up on [Java for loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763131/java-for-loop-syntax) for doing things like calculating the total prices. Best of luck.

Comment: Yes, acattle is right. One of your mistakes is that you're assigning `0` to your `items` object, when it is not an integer, it is an object of class `ArrayList`.

Comment: @zaidaus I was gonna ask that next because now knowing what I know it doesn't make sense to initialize to 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your `addItem()` method, you can do this:

```
Item item = new Item(description, price, isTaxable);          
this.item.add(item);
```

**Explanation:**

You already have `Item` *array list* which is `private ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();`

Which means you can store all your *Item*  objects in them by calling `this.item.add(item);`

**So, basically what above code does ?**

**1)** Creates new *Item* object

**2)** Populates *Item* object with values (description, price, isTaxable)

**3)** Then adds *Item* object into *Item array list*.

Comment: @acattle, Hmm, I appreciate what you are saying. Let me explain the code.

Comment: @acattle does the item.java get used in the array created in the first segment of code. trying to put the pieces together

Comment: @JDMshifter, it will be used once you create Item object and populate Item object with values as I have suggested in the answer.

Comment: @JDMshifter, see my answer, short answer: yes the Item.java is the Item class you see in the first segment of code

Comment: @Ravi Trivedi I think why I was so confused was because I didn't know you could call a class in array

Comment: @JDMshifter, That is not calling class in an array. It is called parameterized array. What that means is that your array is of type `Item`.

Comment: @RaviTrivedi so it would be kinda like a specified type that he created.

Comment: @JDMshifter, Yes, you can specify the *Type* when you create an array.  It is Java Generics concept. You may want to read Java Generics.

Comment: @RaviTrivedi I know the basics like string,int,double arrays but he didn't explain this far.

Comment: @JDMshifter, That's alright. We read something only after we come to know something about. And that's fair !

Comment: @JDMshifter, Please accept the answer if this has resolved your main issue, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The teacher has provided you with the following member variable:

```
private ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
```

This is an `ArrayList` containing `Item` objects. The class you've provided, "Item.java", contains the definition of the `Item` class.

If you consult the Java API documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28E%29), you'll see that one of the methods provided for an object of class `ArrayList` is the `add` method:

```
public boolean add(E e)
```

Which "Appends the specified element to the end of this list." Using that method, you can add items of the class `Item` to your list.

So in your `addItems` method, you could create a new `Item` object and add that to your list of items like so:

```
Item item = new Item(description, price, isTaxable);
items.add(item);
```

Here we've created a new object of class Item using the provided description, price and isTaxable variables. We then add the item we've just created to our list of items.