# Appending Arraylist to TextView

Tags: java, android, arraylist, textview

I am trying to add Arraylist to Text View But it gives an error while adding it to TextView
Declaration of Arraylist is:

```
    ArrayList<Integer> a=new ArrayList<Integer>();


    1.       int arraylistSize = a.size();

    2.       for(int i = 0; i < arraylistSize; i++){

    3.  textview1.setText(a[i]);

    4.  textview1.setText("*");
```

At line 3 it gives "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList"

Answer (score 4):

a    textview1.setText(a[i]); => textview1.setText(a.get(i));

or something like:

```
for(Integer i : a) textview1.setText(i);
```

I don't see how this will produce any kind of desired functionality, line 4 will override line 3 and each iteration of line 3 will override the previous one.  After the loop executes you will end up with * in the textview1.

Answer (score 3):

You will want to use ArrayList's get(index) operation. i.e. a.get(i).

If you are looking to see 1*2*3*4..etc.. printed out as text in the textview. you will want to append all these integers together into one string. Example:

```
String s = "";
for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
     s += a.get(i) + "*";
}
textview1.setText(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `append` method in `textview`

```
for (int i=0;i<a.size();i++){
textview1.append(a.get(i) + "*");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(String i : a)
   textview1.append(i + "\n\n");
```

Comment: Its always a good idea to write a small explanation of your solution. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [short hand method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763131/java-for-loop-syntax) of iterating over a list as such:

```
ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (Integer i : a) {
    textview1.setText(Integer.toString(i) + "*");
}
```