# Using UUID.randomUUID() and calling method multiple times?

Tags: java, list, uuid, nanotime

For a class assignment I have to compare different lists' performance with one another's using UUID.randomUUID().toString() to insert a few thousand random strings in a list and record how long it takes with the nanoTime() method. I just can't recall how to set the amount of calls to my add method for my list to a certain number, or how to do it with the UUID.randomUUID(), at least.

```
newbieList.add(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
```

is what I have, which just inserts one random string, of course.

I know this is a simple question probably but I couldn't find any answers Googling or here, so help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Why the down vote? It is an easy question, but a valid one. And if you are just starting the answer to stuff like this is actually not that easy to find.

Comment: I agree with @JensSchauder .. Why the downVote??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put it in a for loop. A for loop is used for repeating stuff when you know at the beginning how often you want to repeat.

See this [answer to a related question for lots of examples for various for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7763169/66686).

Comment: for a moment.. I was actually wondering if the OP was asking this :).

Comment: @TheLostMind It's easy to forget the struggles at the beginning of programming.