# Java Foreach with a condition

Tags: java, foreach

Is it possible for Java foreach to have conditions?

For example,

```
for(Foo foo : foos && try == true)
{
//Do something
}
```

Is there an equivalent to this, such that I can put an AND condition inside `for`?

Comment: For more information you may take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/3433775/197574

Comment: \@anyone, Please ping me when a lib is available.  Thank you so very much in advance!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No.

You could use a while loop instead.

```
Iterator iterator = list.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: probably min^infinity minifies min.

Comment: @NandKumarTekale - that's not Nim's problem; he's going by what the OP wrote.

Comment: answer should address the added condition though

Answer (score 13):

No, there is nothing like that. The "enhanced for loop" is a completely separate construct that does nothing except lopp through the iterator returned by its `Iterable` parameter.

What you can do is this:

```
for(Foo foo : foos)
{
   //Do something
   if(!condition){
       break;
   }
}
```

Comment: guess foreach is not that elegant after all.

Comment: It's a tool for a certain kind of tasks.

Comment: @TJ-: Actually, I'd say that doing one thing only makes it *more* elegant. The C-like for loop that lumps iteration, initialization and arbitrarily complex conditions and iteration steps together in one super-powerful construct, only to be used in exactly the same way 95% of the cases *that* is horribly inelegant.

Answer (score 8):

No, **foreach** is specially designed only for iterating all the elements of an array or collection.

If you want you can check condition inside it and use **break** keyword for getting out of loop in middle.

Answer (score 3):

In `Java 8`, you **can** do it. For example :

```
foos.forEach(foo -> {
        if(try) {
          --your code--
        }
    });
```

Comment: Too easy to provide a -1 without any explanation.

Comment: because you just put the condition inside the loop body. In Java 8 the original question will like: Is it possible for Java 8 foreach to have conditions? For example: `foos.forEach(try, foo -> { --your code--
 });`, where `try` is Predicate.

Comment: that's very Scala like!  for(x <- c; if cond) yield {...}

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing you can get is probably to filter the initial iterable:

```
for(Foo foo : filter(foos)) {
    //Do something
}
```

Where the filter method returns an iterable containing only those elements for which your condition holds. For example with Guava you could write the filter method like this:

```
Iterable<String> filter(Iterable<String> foos) {
    return Iterables.filter(foos, 
            input -> input.equals("whatever");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

for-each cannot have conditions, here is the equivalent of what you asked for:

```
Iterator<Foo> iterator = foos.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext() &&  condition == true) {
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use combination of `stream`, `filter` and `forEach`.

For example:

```
    List<String> collection = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "baz");

    collection.stream()
    .filter(e-> !"bar".equals(e))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

You get:

```
foo
baz
```

P.S.
This will work on Java 8 and later.