# add additional parameters to foreach loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, foreach, traversal

I have a foreach loop that goes

```
boolean doesWordMatch = false;
for(Character[] charArr : charSets)
{
  if(doesWordMatch)
    //dosomething
  else
    break;
}
```

I was wondering, is there anyway to put the condition into the for loop? e.g.

```
for(Character[] charArr : charSets && doesWordMatch == true)
{
  //dosomething
}
```

edit-- Right, so would this be possible in a while loop? :o

Comment: you loop over a **collection** not over a **Condition** !

Comment: There's no *enhanced while* loop, so it's anybody's guess what you have in mind.

Comment: Probably answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104522/java-foreach-with-a-condition

Comment: Why do you call condition inside for loop in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this cannot be done in an *enhanced for-loop*.

You could try the following:

```
for (Character[] charArr : charSets) {
    if (!doesWordMatch) {
        break;
    }
    //do interesting things
}
```

I believe this is also more concise than having everything in the looping declaration.

Comment: That's basically OP's first example, did you notice it?

Comment: Think he meant that its neater then if() {} else {} :D I wonder-- would this then be possible in while loops then?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I see a fundamental difference. What I believe the OP was thinking to do is to wrap everything around in `if-else`-statements, leading to tremendous code clutter with more conditions. What I propose is to move the boolean check forward, before the interesting stuff starts to happen.

Comment: @GwenWong I do not see a way to do it nicely.

Comment: I grant that this might be one (smaller) aspect of what bothers OP in his (her?) code.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the "if" block out of the for loop, then you can do it the old-fasioned way.

```
Iterator<Character[]> i=charSets.iterator();
for(Character[] charArr=i.next(); i.hasNext() && doesWordMatch == true; charArr=i.next() ) {
        // do something
}
```

Comment: This snippet is not robust to an empty collection, but I agree with the suggestion of using an iterator and a standard for-loop if the OP wants to inline an extra condition into their for-loop check.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to create a mapping between `charArr` and `doesWordMatch`:

```
Map<Character[], Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(charArr, doesWordMatch);

for(Map.Entry<Character[], Boolean> myEntry : map.entrySet()) {
    if(myEntry.getValue()) {
        // do something with myEntry.getKey();
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for, but I can't think of any other reason for wanting the `doesWordMatch` variable into the loop. In this case, `doesWordMatch` can be different for each `charArr`.

Answer (score 0):

Use an iterator and a standard for-loop with a blank increment statement:

```
Character[] curr;
for(Iterator<Character[]> iter = charSets.iterator(); iter.hasNext() && doesWordMatch;) {
  curr = iter.next();
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Will the boolean variable doesWordMatch change in the for-loop?

If not, I would suggest:

```
if(doesWordMatch)
  for(Character[] charArr : charSets)
  {
    //dosomething
  }
}
```

Comment: I strongly believe that the `doesWordMatch` changes during the iteration, else imho this whole question would make no sense.

Comment: I wasn't asking you, I was asking the OP. 
If you are correct your suggestion above isn't that nice, why enter the for loop if you know that you shouldn't?

Comment: @skiwi And why are you downvoting a suggestion better than yours just because I have a question in it that you think you have the answer to?

Comment: I have not downvoted you, please keep your comments for yourself.