# For each loop in the null list

Tags: java, foreach

If we do a foreach loop in an empty collection, simply no actions will be taken. But how should work the structure in the case, when the collection is null?

```
Collection<String> c=null;
....
for(String item:c){
   println(item);
}
```

I can run the code and see the null reference exception. But what should be the behaviour exactly? I can't find any manual page about that.

I know that the exception is thrown at the header, because the collection is null.  But I want to know HOW the exception is thrown. It could be done by if, or by Objects.requireNonNull(), or in some other ways, or as it is shown in the David's answer.

Comment: check [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2-300-A.2)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Thank you. I didn't find that myself. If you did put it as an answer (citation, not only reference), I would check it.

Comment: @davidxxx answer is perfect, now that he added the JLS reference [:-)

Comment: @Ben I have read those posts, all of them. There is no mention on the null collection case. Now, after reading answer of David and comment of Carlos, I understand the problem, but those posts are not explaining my question well enough.

Comment: @Gangnus I do agree that expanding this is a possibility but as it's explicitely mentioned that the enhanced for calls `iterator()` on the collection it's expected to throw a `NullPointerException` when there is nothing to call on. But I agree that it's not a bad idea to clarify that topic again. Would have done it by expanding an answer on the linked topic though over asking a new question (although I don't want to say that asking a new question was in any way wrong!)

Comment: @Ben If I would add a comment there, I (and we all) would never get that nice answer of David.

Comment: @Ben I wanted to know HOW the exception is thrown. It could be done by if, or by Objects.requireNonNull(), or in some other ways, or as it is shown in the David's answer

Comment: @Gangnus totally valid. The only thing is that now the information on a roughly similar topic is split between two questions. Merging it in there would be a net gain for the community, or? As I said, this question was certainly the correct way to go about it but the knowledge that was obtained here now could be referenced over there so if someone stumbles on the post they also find the information provided here.

Comment: @Ben I added a reference there. But, what is interesting, that question asked for the code generated. And no answer there contains byte code. On the contrary, here we have it.

Comment: Then it's even better that it's now referenced to finally provide what was asked for from the bat.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A enhanced for (or foreach) after compilation uses under the hood an `Iterator` to iterate on the collection as stated by the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2-300-A.2) :

> The enhanced for statement is equivalent to a basic for statement of
>   the form:
>
> ```
> for (I #i = Expression.iterator(); #i.hasNext(); ) {
>     {VariableModifier} TargetType Identifier =
>         (TargetType) #i.next();
>     Statement
> }
> ```

You can check if yourself by looking the disassembled code of your loop after compilation (`javap -c`) :

```
  3: invokeinterface #2,  1            // InterfaceMethod java/util/Collection.iterator:()Ljava/util/Iterator;
  8: astore_2
  9: aload_2
 10: invokeinterface #3,  1            // InterfaceMethod java/util/Iterator.hasNext:()Z
 15: ifeq          38
 18: aload_2
 19: invokeinterface #4,  1            // InterfaceMethod java/util/Iterator.next:()Ljava/lang/Object;
 24: checkcast     #5                  // class java/lang/String
 27: astore_3
 28: getstatic     #6                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
 31: aload_3
 32: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
 35: goto          9
```

So, it is like if you had written :

```
Collection<String> c = null;
for (Iterator<String> iterator = c.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    String item = iterator.next();          
}
```

Invoking `iterator()` on `null` throws so a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: just adding: the Java Language Specification is clear about that (no need for bytecode) - [JLS 14.14.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2-300-A.2) and somehow [16.2.12.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-16.html#jls-16.2.12-100)

Comment: Thank you especially for byte code representation - I hadn't used it yet.

Comment: @Carlos Heuberger You are right.  I updated with. I keep all the same the disassembled code as it is always pleasant to be able to see/inspect things yourselves.

Comment: @Gangnus You are welcome. I don't use it very often but as I need it it is really useful. Here is a good complement to understand the JVM instructions : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.1.9

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Yes, in bytecode I see exactly the sequence of operation and at which point the exception is thrown - just what I need.

Answer (score 2):

It should throw the exception - plain simple.

Comment: I see it myself. I wanted to know, at which moment the exception is thrown. The answer of davidxxx and comment of Carlos help in my problem.

Answer (score 1):

`foreach` loop compiled into either `iterator` or `index` based loop behind scenes. Whenever it access to the `iterator` for the list `NullPointerException` is thrown for `null` referenced `Iterable object`. Though, why `null` check is not included in the implementation of the java `foreach` is another question. But I think, it keeps the distinction clearer between an `empty list` with a `null list`, which the latter one represents that something already went wrong.

Comment: Of course, it is a great difference, to count apples in an empty sack, or to count them when no sack is given.

Answer (score 0):

It will throw NullPointerException because collection is null and you are trying to iterate a collection which has referenced null. If collection is empty then it will not throw the exception and code will work fine.

Comment: I wanted to know HOW the exception is thrown. It could be done by if, or  by Objects.requireNonNull(), or in some other ways, or as it is shown in the David's answer.