# Why is the loop variable effectively final when using for-each?

Tags: java, lambda, final

- case 1: it can work when using for-each loop：

```
    private void m10(String[] arr) {
        for (String s : arr) {
            Supplier<String> supplier = () -> {
                System.out.println(s);
                return null;
            };
            supplier.get();
        }
    }
```

or

```
    private void m10(Object[] arr) {
        for (Object s : arr) {
            Supplier<String> supplier = () -> {
                System.out.println(s);
                return null;
            };
            supplier.get();
        }
    }
```

- case 2: it will catch compile-time error

```
    private void m11(String[] arr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            Supplier<String> supplier = () -> {
                System.out.println(arr[i]);
                return null;
            };
            supplier.get();
        }
    }
```

In case 2, I know the variable `i` is not effectively final because its value changed between loop iterations. But I cannot understand why the lambda can work in case 1.

Comment: Would be helpful to see how `s` is scoped: [How is Java's for loop code generated by the compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3433775/5761558)

Comment: Because `for(final String s : arr)` would be valid too. That’s what *effectively final* means; adding the `final` keyword would not break it.

Comment: You can think of case 1 as equal to doing `String s = arr[i];` first thing in the loop in case 2. This too will allow you to do `System.out.println(s);` inside the lambda because `s` is effectively final. (And thanks to @Slaw for pointing out that this is a duplicate; there’s a lot more information in the original question.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`s` is never changed (`s = ...`). So the compiler says *"yeah, we could theoretically mark this as `final`"*. That is what is meant by *effectively final*. I.e. you did not mark it `final` but you could and it would still compile.

In case you are wondering about the enhanced for-loop:

```
for (String s : arr)
```

The variable does not live outside of the scope of the `for` and does not get re-assigned. I.e. it is **not**:

```
String s = null;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    s = arr[i];
    ...
}
```

The variable is created inside the loop, so its scope is limited to the loop. It is not re-used but thrown away and re-created each iteration:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    String s = arr[i];
    ...
}
```

Take a close look at the two examples. In the first, you could not write `final String s = null;`, because we are re-assigning it during the loop `s = arr[i];`. But in the second example we can, because the variable `s` is only known within one iteration and then thrown away again. So `final String s = arr[i];` is fine.

As a side note, this also explains why you can not use `s` after the loop. It is unknown and destroyed already, its scope is limited to the loop.

Answer (score 4):

Because the scope of `s` is a single iteration, there isn't one `s` that changes value, but one effectively final `s` for each loop iteration.

It would be like writing your case 2 in the following way, which does compile

```
private void m11(String[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        String s = arr[i];
        Supplier<String> supplier = () -> {
            System.out.println(s);
            return null;
        };
        supplier.get();
    }
}
```