While using a for-each loop in Java with toCharArray, does it call toCharArray with every iteration?
String test = "123456789";

for(char c: test.toCharArray()) {
   System.out.println(c);
}

My question here is: does test.toCharArray() get called everytime during the iteration i.e. in here 9 times?
Also, I know that something like size for a collection or length for an array are attributes, so even though they are accessed during a for-i loop, it is just an access of the property and nothing more.
Please correct me if I am wrong about this assumption of mine.
The answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1618405/10120165 partially answers my question. Is there anyway to be sure of this? Also, I could not locate that documentation easily.

It's invoked just once.

documentation: Java Language Specification 14.14.2. The enhanced for statement
